# LINQ to Entities Query Optimization - Poor Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got some very poor performing queries all over the place in my EF6 implemented app.  Here is one query that is taking nearly 3000 MS to be performed. (localhost to external sql server)

```
dash.UserActivities = db.Activities.Include(a => a.Customer).Include(a => a.ActivityType).Where(a => a.AssignedUserId == userId)
    .Where(a => a.IsComplete == false).OrderBy(a => a.DueDateTime).Take(10).Select(
        a => new ActivityViewModel()
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            CustomerFirstName = a.Customer.FirstName,
            CustomerLastName = a.Customer.LastName,
            ActivityType = a.ActivityType.Name,
            DueDateTime = a.DueDateTime,
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Clearly something doesn't feel right about this, it is probably something obvious.  But I have no clue what it is!

#### UPDATE

The SQL being generated from this is:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[DueDateTime] AS [DueDateTime]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[DueDateTime] AS [DueDateTime], 
        [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CustomerId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ActivityTypes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ActivityTypeId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[IsComplete]) AND ([Extent1].[AssignedUserId] = 037da3f4-99cc-4338-8b36-491ca0fcfcb1 /* @p__linq__0 */)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[DueDateTime] ASC
```

Comment: Did you check the SQL that's being generated for your query?

Comment: Well, for starters, you can cut out both `Include` statements, as you're not projecting either collection in the results of your query.

Comment: @Servy please see the update above.

Comment: I assume you meant to reply to @MarcinJuraszek there, as he's the one who asked for the generated SQL.

Comment: @Servy of course!  Once you start being an idiot, it just continues!  Sorry about that.

Comment: SQL query looks about right. You should run it against your database directly and verify execution time and generated execution plan. Do you have all the indexes right?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - updated to show the SQL.

Comment: Working on that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarcinJuraszek suggested in the comments, we needed to perform these queries locally and audit the performance here.  Using tuning adviser, we found many opportunities for improvement.

Answer (score -3):

First thing, turn of LazyLoading in the context if enabled... Performance are bad, really bad. And the include will be disregarded if enabled.

In your example, as you are using some real class in your query, the Select is not done on the SQL Server side, but via C#. That means it will do the join operation on all table, do a "select *"  as he does not know what fields he will need, and then map it. Slow, really slow.

```
    dash.UserActivities = db.Activities..Where(a => a.AssignedUserId == userId && a => !a.IsComplete).OrderBy(a => a.DueDateTime).Select( a => new {  
                Id = a.Id,
                CustomerFirstName = a.Customer.FirstName,
                CustomerLastName = a.Customer.LastName,
                ActivityType = a.ActivityType.Name,
                DueDateTime = a.DueDateTime
  }).Take(10).Select(
            a => new ActivityViewModel()
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                CustomerFirstName = a.CustomerFirstName,
                CustomerLastName = a.CustomerLastName ,
                ActivityType = a.ActivityType 
                DueDateTime = a.DueDateTime,
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: The generated SQL shows that the query provider can support what he's doing just fine, and that it is selecting out only the columns needed.  There are indeed some query providers that don't support this functionality, but this one clearly does.  The lazy loading is also not relevant here given that he's not projecting out entire entities containing properties that could be loaded lazily.

Comment: Not true. Look at generated SQL author added to the question.

Comment: When I wrote my answer the SQL was not displayed :) Sorry guys